# C# Change Screen Orientation programmatically

Tags: c#

i want to create a little console application that change the screen orientation. The Programm detect the current orientation, and change to other orientation.
Ive searched in the community and i can not find any right solution for my issue. I hope now that someone can help me.

Thanks

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Ok thanks, i have this solution not seen while i searched in this forum because it asked 3 years ago.

Answer (score 3):

You can start from [MSDN Changing Screen Orientation Programmatically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms812499.aspx)